# Replace a sef of characters in c++with the the least number of code lines

Tags: c++, string

I am using the following function in c++ to replace a set of ASCII characters.

```
std::string debug::convertStringToEdiFormat(const char *ediBuffer) {
  std::string local(ediBuffer);
  std::replace(local.begin(), local.end(), '\037', ':');
  std::replace(local.begin(), local.end(), '\031', '*');
  std::replace(local.begin(), local.end(), '\035', '+');
  std::replace(local.begin(), local.end(), '\034', '\'');
  return std::string(local);
}
```

the problem is that it is too long. If I want to replace like 100 characters it will have 100 lines of code. Is there another function that takes less code and allows me to do the same?

Comment: You must traverse the string once. Each time you call replace, the string is traversed. Use a map to map your characters and replace the characters in a for loop.

Comment: What you are trying to do is quite a specific transformation. If you can't extract a relationship between the characters you want to replace and the characters they are replaced by, I'm afraid you have to write as many lines as you have replacements to do.

Comment: And as @ZDF said there are more efficient ways, like using a map in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
array< char, 256 > m;
// fill m
//...
m['\037'] = ':';
m['\031'] = '*';
m['\035'] = '+';
m['\034'] = '\'';
//...
string s{ "Hello world!" };
for (auto& c : s)
  c = m[c];
```

If all you need is change just a couple of characters, you may use [std::transform](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform):

```
auto my_transform = [](const char c)
{
  switch (c)
  {
    case '\037': return ':';
    case '\031': return '*';
    case '\035': return '+';
    case '\034': return '\'';
    default: return c;
  }
};

std::string s{ "\037\031\035\034" };
std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), my_transform);
```

See the [live example.](https://www.ideone.com/MYT2KZ)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an unordered_map and one loop?

```
static const std::unordered_map<char, char> a = {{'\037', ':'}, {'\031', '*'}, {'\035', '+'}};

void convertStringToEdiFormat(std::string &ediBuffer) {
  for (auto& c : ediBuffer)
    {
        c = a.at(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: unsorted_map -> unordered_map. I'd like to edit it myself but I can't edit if less than 6 characters are to change (WTF?)

Comment: This throws an exception on a string containing anything not in your `a`.

Comment: It is a small sample. You should take that into consideration. But some systems have exceptions disable

Answer (score 0):

Best approach is to extract a function/functor which does character conversion.
Here is fully functional functor which is able to perform conversion in both directions.

```
class ReplaceEncoder {
public:
    ReplaceEncoder() {
        initArray(m_encode);
        initArray(m_decode);
    }

    void updateEncoding(const std::string &from, const std::string &to) {
        assert(from.size() == to.size());
        for (int i=0; i<from.size()) {
             m_encode[from[i]] =   to[i];
             m_decode[  to[i]] = from[i];
        }
    }

    char encode(char ch) const {
         return m_encode[static_cast<unsigned char>(ch)];
    }

    char decode(char ch) const {
         return m_decode[static_cast<unsigned char>(ch)];
    }

    char operator()(char ch) const {
         return encode(ch);
    }

private:
    void initArray(std::array<char, 0x100> &arr) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i) {
            arr[i] = static_cast<char>(i);
        }
    }

private:
    std::array<char, 0x100> m_encoder;
    std::array<char, 0x100> m_decoder;
};

ReplaceEncoder encrypt;
encrypt.updateEncoding("absdet", "gmbstp");

string s{ "Hello world!" };
std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), encrypt);
```